# Angular Reactive Forms - Child property input form not binding correctly to parent created FormGroup

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a function which dynamically creates a new instance of a FormGroup element.

```
appendPersoenlicheVerhaeltnisse(typeOfPerson: string, index) {
  try {
    (<FormGroup>(
      this.BBForm.get('gesellschafterAngaben.gesellschafter.' + index + ".angabenZurPerson." + typeOfPerson)
    )).addControl('anlagePV', this.createPVerhaltSections());
    this.hasAnlagePV[index] = true;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  this.BBForm.updateValueAndValidity();
  this.cd.detectChanges;
  this.hasAnlagePV.splice(this.hasAnlagePV.indexOf(this.hasAnlagePV[index]), index, true);}
```

The function that specifies the controls is inside the parent :

```
createPVerhaltSections(): FormGroup {
return this.fb.group({
  familienstand: [null, Validators.required],
  anzahlKinder: [null, [Validators.pattern('^[0-9]{0,5}$')]],
  staatsangehoerigkeit: [
    null,
    [Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-ZäÄöÖüÜß]{1,40}$')],
  ],
  barBank: [null, [Validators.pattern(this.similarRegex)]],
  beleihungswert: [null, [Validators.pattern(this.similarRegex)]],
  belastung: [null],
  sonstigeBelastung: this.fb.group({
    betrag: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.min(0.01)]],
    form: [null, Validators.required],
  }),
  vermoegenEingesetzt: [null],
  verbindlichkeiten: [null],
  zahlungsverpflichtungen: [null],
  eventualverbindlichkeiten: [null],
  jahreseinkommenNetto: [null],
  ausbildungen: this.fb.group({
    ausbildung: [null, Validators.required],
  }),
  beurteilungen: this.fb.group({
    beurteilungVon: [null, Validators.required]
  }),
  letzteTaetigkeit: [null],
  arbeitslosSeit: [null],
  arbeitslosVergangenheit: [null],
  dauerArbeitslosigkeit: [null],
  bereitsTaetigkeitImBetrieb: [null],
  bereitsErfahrungBrancheProdukt: [null],
  dauerBerufserfahrung: [null],
  erlaeuterungBeruflicheTaetigkeit: [null],
  unterschrift: this.fb.group({
    datum: [null],
    ort: [null],
  }),
});
```

}

Afterwards, these controls are sent to the child component to be displayed

```
 <span *ngIf="hasAnlagePV[i]" class="p-col-12">
                        <p-accordion [multiple]="true">
                            <span class="p-col-12" [formGroupName]="i">
                              <p-accordionTab class="p p-m-1 p-p-2">
                                <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                                  <div
                                    class=" p-p-2 p-d-flex p-jc-between p-ai-center my-width-class header-with-buttons">
                                    <div #text>
                                      <span class="p p-m-3">102</span>
                                      <span> Anlage Persönliche Verhältnisse </span>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </ng-template>
                                <ng-template pTemplate="content">
                                  <app-pverhalt
                                    [pVerhaltForm]="BBForm.get('gesellschafter.gesellschafterAngaben.'+i+'.angabenZurPerson.natuerlichePerson.anlagePV')"
                                    (myEmitter)="updatePVerhaltBBVFormValues($event, index, i)">
                                  </app-pverhalt>
                                </ng-template>
                              </p-accordionTab>
                            </span>
                        </p-accordion>
                  </span>
```

After multiple tests, I'm certain that the elements are added successfully to the main form, however the button doesn't work as it should and the child component doesn't receive the created FormGroup correctly. [This is the error that shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmFHa.png) and here is what the child element receives.
pVerhaltForm: FormGroup;

```
 @Input() set setPVerhaltForm(value: FormGroup) {

this.pVerhaltForm = value; }

 get getPVerhaltForm(): FormGroup {

return this.pVerhaltForm;  }
```

I am confident after many hours trying to resolve the issue, that the problem lies here in this line of code

```
 <app-pverhalt [pVerhaltForm]="BBForm.get('gesellschafter.gesellschafterAngaben.'+i+'.angabenZurPerson.natuerlichePerson.anlagePV')"
                                    
    (myEmitter)="updatePVerhaltBBVFormValues($event, index, i)">
                                      </app-pverhalt>
```

since the child element is not initialized at all when created.

Can anyone offer me any insight as to how I can fix this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please add code in a code block, not as image.

Comment: you're try to get the FormContol in error way. use the get and concatenate .i. it's for FormArray And I can not see a formArray in your code. BTW if you pass a FormGroup or a FormControl you needn't use a emitter, because the "object" is the same, any change in the FormGroup in your component is like you've change in parent

Comment: Could you please give me an example of what you mean, since I'm not too sure I understand you?